# Can't upload binary data via RestKIT 0.22 - server receives 0 length stream

Tags: objective-c, wcf, rest, restkit

our server is WCF and has a method that accepts binary data and stores it:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", //@WSF-687
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     UriTemplate = "File/{fileName}")]
ContentResponse UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileStream);
```

our client side is objective-c and we are trying to post an object (image / etc...) to the server using RESTKit - but the stream in the other side is always 0 with no content...

Restkit code:

```
NSData* rawData //this is the data we want to send
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject: data path:OUR_SERVER_PATH parameters:nil success:nil failure: nil]
```

the call succeeds but the server receives empty stream..

when we used another method of creating form data - it worked but it appended the form data to the content which is problematic (we need it raw).

anything we missed?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading raw data with no other formatted (JSON / XML) data you should not be using RestKit, that isn't what it's for. You have access to AFNetworking, or you could use the Apple provided API, and these are much more suitable for your requirement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
can you provide a code snippet?
is it possible to integrate the requests with the requests queue they are providing?

Also, we managed to download files with RestKIT when the result was not JSON - but binary data. how's that possible that download is supported but not upload?

Comment: It's not that it isn't supported as such, it's just not designed for. Was the response just binary data (no wrapper)? You can use a custom serialiser to do it, but it's usually overkill (unless you need to make a JSON request and receive binary back). If you create your own operation then you can add it to the `operationQueue` of your object manager.

Comment: no wrapper what so ever.
i'm using

'getWithAction' for the raw data, in the success handler i just take 'operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseData' and i get the NSData which is raw data (no json, etc...) (as u said)

if it's not possible using RESTKit - how do i do it with AFNetworking?

Comment: Use `requestWithMethod:path:parameters:` on the object managers http manager, then add the data to the request, then create an `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, set the completion blocks and execute.

Comment: Amazing :) it worked!
we'll extend the RKObjectManager now to add a support for that.

Thank you very much Wain!

Comment: ArialB: Thats exactly what I am looking for. Can you post your snippet what you have done? I also need to Post some data, but expect parsable JSON from my datasource.